# is it efficient to store my online socket server users on redis?and if yes then how?

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, redis

I am building a web socket application using node and i want to store my currently connected users ,so i saved it as a user Id key and socket Id value but when the user disconnect i only knows it's socket Id so i will not be able to remove it from Redis (since Redis only allow search by key) so how would i solve it ? i tried to reverse the key and value but it's impossible as a socket id is not unique

````
const isUserExist = async (socketId) => {
  return await redisClient.get(socketId);
};

const addUser = async (socketId, userId) => {
  if (await isUserExist(socketId)) return console.log("user already exist");
  await redisClient.set(socketId, userId);
  console.log("user is set inside database ");
};```
````

Comment: Sure, you can use redis. If socket id isn't unique then what is the point of socket id?

Comment: but how can i search by value?

Comment: Does your app not know what the socket IDs of its own sockets are...?

Comment: i need to delete the disconnected users from redis , so i will delete the id of the user as it' my key so i need to delete the crossponding user id to delete it , but how can i know it in server?

Comment: Doesn't the server know which sockets and users disconnected?

Comment: no he only knows the socket id

Comment: so what's the problem? Seems like you can delete the socket ID from redis

Comment: io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("user connected " + socket.id);
  socket.on("addUser", (id) => {
    addUser(socket.id, id);
  });
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log(socket.id + " is disconncted");
  });
});

Comment: but the key in redis with the user id and i don't have reach for it

Comment: Does redisClient.get(socketID) not work?

Comment: i soled it by assiging new attribute to socket object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have actually discovered that socket object carries the socket id of the current connected user , so i used it and my problem was solved and we also need to store the id as the key and the socket id as the value